# Comparing identical dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to compare 2 dataframe.

With the code:

```
supp_chg = supp_chg == supp_bal
```

I have the error:

```
 File "/Users/delalma/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/__init__.py", line 1567, in f
    "Can only compare identically-labeled " "DataFrame objects"
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects
```

check 1:

```
print(type(supp_chg), type(supp_bal))
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

check2:

```
             circulating_supply
currency                            
BCH                         18225550
BTC                         18163250
ETH                        109296900
QASH                       350000000
XRP                      43653780000          
 circulating_supply
currency                    
BCH             1.822705e+07
BTC             1.816495e+07
ETH             1.093086e+08
QASH            3.500000e+08
XRP             4.365378e+10
```

Why does it not work? everything is identical.
Any help would be appreciated please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

`df1.equals(df2)`

the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html) explain it the best

> This function allows two Series or DataFrames to be compared against each other to see if they have the same shape and elements. NaNs in the same location are considered equal. The column headers do not need to have the same type, but the elements within the columns must be the same dtype.

Comment: No but it worked. Any explanation about the reason please/?